# How can I see multiple terms on a single view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8

I have a content type called "Listing". This listing has a taxonomy reference called "Amenities". A single listing can have several or no amenities and each term has a field on it called "icon".

I want to create a view that shows:

- TITLE
- Amenity 1, Amenity 2, Amenity 3

Instead of text, I want to show icons.

I was able to figure out that you can use "relationships" to get to the icon field on the term. However, it only shows ONE term from the list. There doesn't seem to be any aggregation or grouping by happening. Which means it shows the same listing over and over, for each term. Instead of showing the listing once, and all the term images below that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Grouping can be enabled in Format section of your View [Format > Settings]. Select title field for grouping and then exclude it from display to avoid rendering it twice.
Aggregation in this case will not give you the result that you're looking for.